# Function return pointer to another type of function - C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
bool (__fastcall fun)(float par1, float par2)
{
    return (par1 == par2) ? true : false;
}

bool (__fastcall *newFun())(std::string str)
{
    //...
    return fun;
}
```

I have error: error return value type does not match the function type.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why the `std::string` ?

Comment: @Quentin It's a fragemet of full code. The paremeter `std::string` will be use later.

Comment: What's wrong is as the error message says; you're trying to return a type that doesn't match.  `(std::string str)` is not `(float par1, float par2)`.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth I know this, but I'm interested in how to improve the code

Comment: Perhaps a good starting point is to read the compiler error messages and warnings

Comment: @pjaniak: Improve the code by returning a pointer to a function of the correct type.

Comment: without knowing what you intend to do, all we can tell you is what the compiler is telling you: you can't return a pointer to a different function type.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth hmm, I think that is possible to return pointer of another function type, but question is how?

Comment: Change the signature of `fun`, or change the return type of `newFun`.  As @bolov says, we don't know what you're trying to do, so can only give you generic advice.

Comment: not it is not possible to return pointer to another function type (I mean you could because of the "shoot yourself in the foot" C rule, but then you would... well... shoot yourself in the foot).

Comment: @bolov Ok. Thank you all for your answers. I consider the subject closed.

Comment: you have the option to delete your own question. But I don't understand why you don't edit the question to tell what you want to achieve so that we can actually help you.

Answer (score 2):

Will this help:

```
bool (__fastcall fun)(float par1, float par2)
{
    return (par1 == par2) ? true : false;
}

bool (__fastcall *newFun(std::string str))(float par1, float par2)
{
    //...
    return fun;
}

int main()
{
    auto p = newFun("someString");
    cout << p(1.0, 1.0) << endl;
    cout << p(1.0, 1.1) << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Maybe you want to read [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

I think it is a quite good discussion of function pointers.